# Powershell-ImportVM Command Compare VM returns the expected result, but when using import-vm inside the script it throws an error

Tags: powershell, import, hyper-v

```
Compare-VM

PS C:\San\SV65\ps> Compare-VM -Path 'C:\San\SV65\hyper-packer\hyper-packer\output-centos8-9\Virtual Machines\FEEBFC7A-7AB7-4C57-A3D4-B3C5593F8FF7.vmcx'
DEBUG:    1+  >>>> Compare-VM -Path 'C:\San\SV65\hyper-packer\hyper-packer\output-centos8-9\Virtual 
Machines\FEEBFC7A-7AB7-4C57-A3D4-B3C5593F8FF7.vmcx'
DEBUG:     ! CALL function '<ScriptBlock>'


VM                 : VirtualMachine (Name = 'packer-centos8-base-g2-9') [Id = 'feebfc7a-7ab7-4c57-a3d4-b3c5593f8ff7']
OperationType      : ImportVirtualMachine
Destination        : F06E0BBCFD35P
Path               : C:\San\SV65\hyper-packer\hyper-packer\output-centos8-9\Virtual
                     Machines\FEEBFC7A-7AB7-4C57-A3D4-B3C5593F8FF7.vmcx
SnapshotPath       : C:\San\SV65\hyper-packer\hyper-packer\output-centos8-9\Snapshots
VhdDestinationPath : C:\San\SV65\hyper-packer\hyper-packer\output-centos8-9\Virtual Hard Disks
VhdSourcePath      :
Incompatibilities  : {}
CheckpointPath     : C:\San\SV65\hyper-packer\hyper-packer\output-centos8-9\Snapshots
```

But when using through scripts

```
 Import-VM -Path 'C:\San\SV65\hyper-packer\hyper-packer\output-centos8-9\Virtual Machines\FEEBFC7A-7AB7-4C57-A3D4-B3C5593F8FF7.vmcx' -Copy -VhdSourcePath 'C:\San\SV65\hyper-packer\hyper-packer\output-centos8-9\Virtual Hard Disks\packer-centos8-base-g2-9.vhdx' -Confirm
```

It returns a error

```
Import-VM : Unable to import virtual machine due to configuration errors.  Please use Compare-VM to repair the virtual machine.
At C:\San\SV65\ps\Import-VM.ps1:26 char:3
+   Import-VM -Path 'C:\San\SV65\hyper-packer\hyper-packer\output-cento ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-VM], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationFailed,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.ImportVM
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Import-VM -Path 'C:\San\SV65\hyper-packer\hyper-packer\output-centos8-9\Virtual Machines\FEEBFC7A-7AB7-4C57-A3D4-B3C5593F8FF7.vmcx' -Copy

works well not with the -vhd